# Sorting array values in ascending order

Tags: php, arrays

I have store array value in the following variable

```
$weight[$cQ][$post]
```

where  `$cQ` is Index and `$post` is article ID , i am storing rating values in the array.

I have used `sort($weight[$cQ][$post])` PHP function for ascending order. But its not ordering array values.. Is there any good solution for sorting array ascending.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [948] => 0.0086665
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [934] => 0.0119
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [932] => 0.0176
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [931] => 0.0125
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [940] => 0.0148
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [930] => 0.01235
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [933] => 0.01715
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [936] => 0.0168
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [945] => 0.0117665
        )
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sort($weight[$cQ]);`?

Comment: okay i have used `sort($weight[$cQ][$post]);` , still no output !

Comment: `asort($weight[$cq][$post]);` ?

Comment: @user2345691 See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

It assumes every array has only one element as per your example array. If it has many, modify it accordingly.

```
function cmp( $a, $b ) {
    $key1 = array_keys( $a ); // all array keys in first array
    $key2 = array_keys( $b ); // all array keys in second array

    if ( $a[ $key1[ 0 ] ] == $b[ $key2[ 0 ] ] ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ( $a[ $key1[ 0 ] ] < $b[ $key2 [ 0 ] ] ) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($weight, 'cmp');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cannot redeclare cmp() (previously declared

Comment: Rename it to something else. You might have a function named `cmp` in your code elsewhere.